# setup.py not found while installing matplotlib in Win7

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is output installing Windows matplotlib:

C:>python -m pip install c:\Users\Joe\Downloads\matplotlib-1.4.3-cp34-none-win3
2.zip
Processing c:\users\joe\downloads\matplotlib-1.4.3-cp34-none-win32.zip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 18, in 
      File "C:\Python34\lib\tokenize.py", line 438, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Joe\App
Data\Local\Temp\pip-vzjagi1p-build\setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>

  File "C:\Python34\lib\tokenize.py", line 438, in open

    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Joe\\App
```

Data\Local\Temp\pip-vzjagi1p-build\setup.py'

```
     Appreciate all advice,   Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

All is fine with installation of matplotlib and works beautifully!!!  I saw that I had changed the postfix ending from "whl" to "zip".  I saw this soon after I posted.   Apologize for being careless.

This site has helped me out so many times and learned many programming tips.
                  cheers and thank you,   Joe